# Different 404 pages depending on the application in Django

Tags: python, django

We are developing a project with several applications using Django. It shares the database, but it has several applications targeting different very different users. Roughly, administrators and final users. The UI of each application is very different. 
I need to create a 404 error page, but seems that I can only create one for all the project. I would like to create different 404 templates and being able to shown them depending on the application (URL) the user is asking for...

For general, clearly invalid URL it's easy, but in the code there are other ways of launching exceptions, like `get_object_or_404` calls.

Anyone knows a way of doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not at all true that you can only create a single 404 page for the entire app. [The documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/views/#the-404-page-not-found-view) explains how you can create a specific 404 handler view, which of course can look at the value of `request.path` to see what URL was requested and render the relevant template.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in a DRY way, perhaps by detecting an app's URL prefix at runtime?

Answer (score 4):

[Write a 404 view](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#write-a-404-page-not-found-view) by setting `handler404`, and not just a template. In that view, try to figure from the url which 404 you should show, and render that.

Comment: Quick note: the handler404 must be in your URLconf to work.